# How to show a sub-tree-item in Qt?

Tags: qt, tree, model-view

Using Qt's model-view framework to represent a tree structure, such as Qt provided simple tree example, the tree view shows the root-tree-item. Any way to show a sub-tree-item, such as a child item of the root?

Comment: I am not sure what the problem is really. Have you had a look at the QTreeView class?

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation for Qt's model/view framework](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/model-view-programming.html#parents-and-children) covers this.

In short, these methods determine the structure of your tree:

- `QAbstractItemModel::index()`, which should return the child indices of a given parent index
- `QAbstractItemModel::parent()`, which should return the parent index of a given child

Note that if you have a large view, these methods must be fast, because the Qt item views will call them *very* often.

---

If you don't absolutely need to implement your own model , I would also suggest looking at [`QTreeWidget`](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qtreewidget.html) (instead of `QTreeView`), which is a much simpler, retained-mode tree view widget. It provides most of the same features with a much easier-to-use (and less error-prone) conceptual model.